# Is there a way to get $.mobile.pageCreate with jQuery 1.3.0 on Webkit browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've tried posting this question before and didn't realize at the time that the problem that I was having was coming from using the jQuery 1.3.0 library.

I'm attempting to create a dialog without user interaction on a page using jQuery mobile. It works in FireFox but fails in all webkit browsers, including Safari, Mobile Safari, and Chrome.

Here's an example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/fskirschbaum/2YTwE/

```
$.mobile.changePage( '#dialog' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
```

I've tried a few different ways to get this thing to work correctly and I feel like I'm hammering my head against a wall. It works if you change the library base to 1.2.0, so it seems to be an issue with 1.3.0, yet I don't see that anyone else seems to be having this problem.

**EDIT:** I have tried attaching this to several events without any success including: pagecreate, pageinit, pageload, and etc. This does not seem to help. I will also point out that this seems to be an issue with this library crashing into another library, on a vanilla page with only jquery and jquery mobile called I can get this to work using the 1.3 library, but not on jsFiddle or in my environment (I am calling many other libraries such as jQueryUI and others, and I have attempted to adjust the order they are called.)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try binding it to an event, e.g. `$('#home').on('pageshow', function () {
$.mobile.changePage( '#dialog' , { transition:"pop", role:"dialog" });
});`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have tried binding it to several different events without success. You can try your suggestion in the jsfiddle I have linked in my post using a webkit browser and see that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that it has something to do with webkit rendering and issues with certain other libraries.

Wrapping the function in `pageshow` did not work for my environment, but wrapping it in `pagecreate` did, which is an event called after createPage. I've not determined why this has happened, but it does work.

http://jsfiddle.net/fskirschbaum/pKw2A/

This solution, however, breaks in Firefox / Gecko rendering, so, the function needs to be wrapped in a browser check to get it to work. Obviously this is not the most elegant solution, but it's a solution none-the-less.

Hopefully this will help anyone else having the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Call `$.mobile.changePage` as below.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#home', function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#dialog');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, if you try it using a webkit based browser using jsFiddle above, you'll see that it does not work as expected. I have tried calling this method using several events and it does not fire at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/fskirschbaum/ktM6Z/

Comment: It is working for me in my web kit browser (chrome), I'll check in fiddle why its not loading on first time. If you navigate to 2nd page and come back to 1st page again, then you can see that it gets fired....!!!!

Comment: I'm seeing that it does fire when you come back to the page, though that's the behavior I'm looking for. I've also found that I can trigger this just fine with user input, it seems to be an issue when the document initial loads getting the dialog to fire without user interaction.

Comment: it seems to be an issue with jsfiddle. If you launch it as standalone app, then it'll fire on initial load itself. I've tried locally and its just working fine.

Comment: I arrived at the same/similar solution but then discovered that pagereate works across all webkit browsers, but does not work correctly in firefox. So, for this case the function is wrapped in a test for webkit now and seems to be working fine enough. The issue that is effecting jsFiddle is also effecting my environment, though I haven't figured out what that problem is exactly.

Thank you for your help.